# How to convert two HashMap into single JSON array using node JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json

I have a data in two HashMap and I'm just printing it using nested for loop as like below:

Note: The input I just mentioned is just for example. The actual hashmap contains runtime data which should stored as key:value pair.

**code:**

```
     let index=0;

     getData.forEach(function(value,key){
         utils.getIndividualComponentCompletLog(key,'./output/output'+index+'.json');
         let getError =  utils.getErrorDataFromComponent('./output/output'+index+'.json');
     getError.forEach(function(value,key){
         console.log(value);
        })
        index++;
    })
```

**Input in the Map:**

```
 Map 1: {"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3"} and  Map 2: {"d":"4","e":"5"}
```

The above code getData and getError is the HasMap, and I just want to create a JSON array using the above two hashmap values as like below:

**Expected:**

```
 {
       data :[
               {
                 "a" : "1",
                 "b" : "2",
                 "c" : "3"
                },
                {
                 "d" : "4",
                 "e" : "5"
                }
             ]
     }
```

I'm not sure how can I achieve this. Can someone give me some idea or any npm package will do this

Also tried JSON.stringify() for single HashMap (not sure how to use it for two hasmap and merge it single). but It doesn't give the above format.

**Updates:**

tried the below lines to convert it to  JSON array. Tried with one hashmap.

**Code**

```
 const output = {
                data: [
                    getError
                ]
              }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(output, null, 2));
```

getError is the hashmap which contains some values

**Output:**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "_data": {},
      "size": 0
    }
  ]
}
{
  "data": [
    {
      "_data": {},
      "size": 0
    }
  ]
}
{
  "data": [
    {
      "_data": {},
      "size": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: could you create a source data and desired data?

Comment: I'm not sure how to build the expected result.

Comment: [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) inside that loop? You may want to provide details about how the input maps look like, and what the output would look. Like if the two maps are `{"a":1,"b":2}` and `{"c":3,"d":4}`, what the "array" at the end would be. `[1,2,3,4]`? Perhaps not an array?

Comment: I want the output as JSON array format as mentioned above in Expected section.

Comment: I feel like there is a catch here because the code is too much simple? https://jsbin.com/pezubus/edit?js

Comment: Updated the question with latest observations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `(Hash)Map`, [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) can make a "regular" object from it. Then `JSON.stringify()` will work:

```js
let map1 = new Map([["a","1"],["b","2"],["c","3"]]);
let map2 = new Map([["d","4"],["e","5"]]);
console.log("With fromEntries()",JSON.stringify(
  {data:[Object.fromEntries(map1),Object.fromEntries(map2)]}
));
console.log("Without fromEntries()",JSON.stringify({data:[map1,map2]}));
```

`Object.fromEntries()` does not seem to work on IdeOne.com (I have no other node.js environment nearby), but a workaround with `forEach()` does:

```js
function objectify(map) {
  let obj = {};
  map.forEach((key,value)=>obj[key]=value);
  return obj;
}
let map1 = new Map([["a","1"],["b","2"],["c","3"]]);
let map2 = new Map([["d","4"],["e","5"]]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(
  {data:[objectify(map1),objectify(map2)]}
));
```

Node.js test: https://ideone.com/Esgc9R

Comment: Still It returned empty json as mentioned above.

Comment: @ArrchanaMohan added a variant which works for me in an online node.js environment. Unfortunately I can not test with the 3rd party  [`HashMap`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hashmap) package, I have to assume that `forEach()` works the same way.